# Selected dropdown value isn't showing in button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Bootstrap dropdown and when dropdown item selected I am setting selected item value to dataTypeName using setState and showing it in button to show which item he/she selected. But for some reason it is not working.

I am generating dropdown in `componentDidMount()` and doing setState in handler function. Is it because the button generated in   `componentDidMount()` and that's why the value doesn't shows up?

Below is the functionality

```
export class GenerateParams extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataTypeName: "Select Type",
            rows: []
        }
    }

    showDataTypeName = (paramName, dataTypeId, dataTypeName) => {
        this.props.handleDataTypes(paramName, dataTypeId, dataTypeName);
        this.setState({
            dataTypeName: dataTypeName
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let content = this.state.rows.slice();    
        this.props.params.map((d, i) => {
            let dataTypes = [];
            if(typeof this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess != 'undefined' && this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.size > 0){
                this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.map((type, i) => {
                    dataTypes.push(<li key={type.get('id')}><a onClick = {() => this.showDataTypeName(d.paramName, type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}> {type.get('name')} </a></li>)
                });
            }
            content.push(<div key={d.paramId}>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <TextInput size="medium" id={d.paramId} value={d.paramName} readOnly/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.state.dataTypeName}
                            <span className="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                            {dataTypes}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
        });

        this.setState({rows:content})
    }

    render(){
        console.log("dataTypeName", this.state.dataTypeName)
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.rows}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put your JSX in state. Set the data in state instead and derive your JSX from state/props in the render method.

Comment: I can't do that in render right because my handler function does setState and thats leading into infinite setState loop warning. Thats why I did that in componentDidMount()

Comment: You should never *invoke* a function that does `setState` directly in render, but it's perfectly fine to have event handlers that call `setState`, e.g. `onClick={() => this.showDataTypeName( ... )}`

Comment: Agreed. But here I am generating dropdown based on list of dropdown items so the event handler is in loop and causing setState infinite issue. Can I use componentWillReceiveProps instead of componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

It is working after generating dropdowns in render instead of componentDidMount.

```
export class GenerateParams extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataTypeName: "Select Type",
            rows: []
        }
    }

    showDataTypeName = (paramName, dataTypeId, dataTypeName) => {
        this.props.handleDataTypes(paramName, dataTypeId, dataTypeName);
        this.setState({
            dataTypeName: dataTypeName
        });
    }

    render(){
        let content = this.state.rows.slice();    
        this.props.params.map((d, i) => {
            let dataTypes = [];
            if(typeof this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess != 'undefined' && this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.size > 0){
                this.props.apiPropertiesSuccess.map((type, i) => {
                    dataTypes.push(<li key={type.get('id')}><a onClick = {() => this.showDataTypeName(d.paramName, type.get('id'), type.get('name'))}> {type.get('name')} </a></li>)
                });
            }
            content.push(<div key={d.paramId}>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <TextInput size="medium" id={d.paramId} value={d.paramName} readOnly/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.state.dataTypeName}
                            <span className="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                            {dataTypes}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
        });
        return(
            <div>
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```